# Stripe returns successful test transaction locally but not on live page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got pages set up to carry out a test transaction on my local server, using SSL w/ MAMP Pro. When submitting I'm getting "credit card charged successfully" and I see the transaction goes through on Stripe's test payment data page. When uploading to the server (w/ valid SSL cert), I'm getting "Error: failed to call pay.php to process the transaction." The odd thing is that the transaction successfully goes through on Stripe's end. I can't figure out why the response is different. There's no errors in my PHP error log, and everything checks out when logging the submitted variables.

buy-controller.js:

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response)
{
    if (response.error) 
    {
        // Stripe.js failed to generate a token. The error message will explain why.
        // Usually, it's because the customer mistyped their card info.
        // You should customize this to present the message in a pretty manner:
        alert(response.error.message);
    } 
    else
    {   
        // Stripe.js generated a token successfully. We're ready to charge the card!
        var token = response.id;
        var fName = $('#first_name').val();
        var lName = $('#last_name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        // alert(fName);
        // alert(lName);  WORKS

        // We need to know what amount to charge. Assume $20.00 for the tutorial. 
        // You would obviously calculate this on your own:
        var price = 70;

        // Make the call to the server-script to process the order.
        // Pass the token and non-sensitive form information.
        var request = $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../pay.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "stripeToken" : token,
                "fName" : fName,
                "lName" : lName,
                "email" : email,
                "price" : price
                }
        });

        request.done(function(msg)
        {
            if (msg.result === 0)
            {
                // Customize this section to present a success message and display whatever
                // should be displayed to the user.
                alert("The credit card was charged successfully!");
            }
            else
            {
                // The card was NOT charged successfully, but we interfaced with Stripe
                // just fine. There's likely an issue with the user's credit card.
                // Customize this section to present an error explanation
                alert("The user's credit card failed.");
            }
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            // We failed to make the AJAX call to pay.php. Something's wrong on our end.
            // This should not normally happen, but we need to handle it if it does.
            alert("Error: failed to call pay.php to process the transaction.");
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#purchase_premium').submit(function(event)


    {
        // immediately disable the submit button to prevent double submits
       $('#purchase_submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var fName = $('#first_name').val();
        var lName = $('#last_name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var cardNumber = $('#cc_number').val();
        var cardCVC = $('#cc_cvc').val(); 

        // Boom! We passed the basic validation, so we're ready to send the info to 
        // Stripe to create a token! (We'll add this code soon.)


        Stripe.createToken({
            number: cardNumber,
            cvc: cardCVC,
            exp_month: $('#cc_expiration_month').val(),
            exp_year: $('#cc_expiration_year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

    });
});
```

Pay.php

```
<?php

// Credit Card Billing 
require_once('includes/Stripe.php');  // change this path to wherever you put the Stripe PHP library!

// For testing purposes
function createLog ($str) {
    $file = 'pay_log.txt';
    // The new person to add to the file
    $str .= "\n";
    // Write the contents to the file, 
    // using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
    // and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
    file_put_contents($file, $str, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

// Helper Function: used to post an error message back to our caller
function returnErrorWithMessage($message) 
{
    $a = array('result' => 1, 'errorMessage' => $message);
    echo json_encode($a);
}



$trialAPIKey = "---";  // These are the SECRET keys!
$liveAPIKey = "---";

Stripe::setApiKey($trialAPIKey);  // Switch to change between live and test environments

// Get all the values from the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstName = $_POST['fName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lName'];
$price = $_POST['price'];


$priceInCents = $price * 100;   // Stripe requires the amount to be expressed in cents

try
{
    // We must have all of this information to proceed. If it's missing, balk.
    if (!isset($token)) throw new Exception("Website Error: The Stripe token was not generated correctly or passed to the payment handler script. Your credit card was NOT charged. Please report this problem to the webmaster.");
    if (!isset($email)) throw new Exception("Website Error: The email address was NULL in the payment handler script. Your credit card was NOT charged. Please report this problem to the webmaster.");
    if (!isset($firstName)) throw new Exception("Website Error: FirstName was NULL in the payment handler script. Your credit card was NOT charged. Please report this problem to the webmaster.");
    if (!isset($lastName)) throw new Exception("Website Error: LastName was NULL in the payment handler script. Your credit card was NOT charged. Please report this problem to the webmaster.");
    if (!isset($priceInCents)) throw new Exception("Website Error: Price was NULL in the payment handler script. Your credit card was NOT charged. Please report this problem to the webmaster.");

    try
    {
        // create the charge on Stripe's servers. THIS WILL CHARGE THE CARD!
        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => $priceInCents,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "card" => $token,
            "description" => $email)
        );

        // If no exception was thrown, the charge was successful! 
        // Here, you might record the user's info in a database, email a receipt, etc.

        // Return a result code of '0' and whatever other information you'd like.
        // This is accessible to the jQuery Ajax call return-handler in "buy-controller.js"
        $array = array('result' => 0, 'email' => $email, 'price' => $price, 'message' => 'Thank you; your transaction was successful!');
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    catch (Stripe_Error $e)
    {
        // The charge failed for some reason. Stripe's message will explain why.
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        returnErrorWithMessage($message);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    // One or more variables was NULL
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    returnErrorWithMessage($message);
}

?>
```

Edit:

By running a  console.log(jqXHR.responseText); in the request.fail block, I'm getting:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: Unable to set verify locations `/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/../data/ca-certificates.crt' `(null)' in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>340</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: failed to create an SSL handle in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>340</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: Failed to enable crypto in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>340</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: unable to connect to ssl://api.stripe.com:443 (Unknown error) in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>340</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_context_get_params() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>350</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  openssl_x509_export() [<a href='function.openssl-x509-export'>function.openssl-x509-export</a>]: cannot get cert from parameter 1 in <b>/nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>355</b><br />
{"result":0,"email":"timh@blah.com","price":"70","message":"Thank you; your transaction was successful!"}
```

It looks like at the end it's trying to pass a successful transaction via AJAX. I'm not sure exactly what to do about this but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off error reporting on the pay.php suppressed the warnings which were causing the JSON response to be invalid.